# setting up mock and fixtures for for multiple pytest unit tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I've been implementing a MySQL client with the later purpose of automating monthly reports.
At the moment, I've got two distinct use cases: Executing a query and printing the results in files. The results are the data queried and some stats about the execution (start time, end time, duration, ...).

My problem is that I must set up the same context for three different tests. The result (Is the data correctly queried ?), the report (Is the execution well informed ?) and the export (Is the data correctly exported into a csv file ?).

I've tried to set up the context using a fixture but the mocks don't work anymore.
I'm wondering if I'm not facing a code smell. I see two solutions: Mocking the object data and then calling the tested method on this mock (how ?) or structuring my code differently, using a writer class that take an instance of my class as input, which I would easily mock.

I must add that this class has a constructor with a single parameter (the path to a file containing a SQL query) and all other attributes are derived.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from string import Template
from shutil import copyfile
import csv
from os import path

from cursor_provider import CursorProvider


REPORT_TEMPLATE = '''
-- START TIME: {start}
-- END TIME: {end}
-- DURATION: {duration}
-- ROWS COUNT: {count}
-- RESULT FILE: {file}
'''


class Query:

    def __init__(self, source, template_vars=None):
        self.source = source
        self.dir = path.dirname(source)
        self.basename = path.basename(source)
        self.raw_name, self.ext = path.splitext(self.basename)
        self.template_vars = template_vars if template_vars is not None else dict()
        self.__interpolated = None
        self.__query_str = None
        self.__result = None
        self.__report = None
        self.__export = None

    @property
    def interpolated(self):
        if self.__interpolated is not None:
            return self.__interpolated
        else:
            template = Template(open(self.source).read())
            interpolated = template.safe_substitute(**self.template_vars)
            unprovided_filtered = re.sub('\n.*\\${\\w+}.*\n', '\n', interpolated)
            self.__interpolated = unprovided_filtered
            return self.__interpolated

    @property
    def query_str(self):
        if self.__query_str is not None:
            return self.__query_str
        else:
            self.__query_str = ' '.join([
                normalize_space(strip_inline_comment(line).strip())
                for line in self.interpolated.split('\n')
                if not is_comment(line) and not is_blank(line)
            ])
            return self.__query_str

    @property
    def result(self):
        if self.__result is not None:
            return self.__result
        else:
            self.__result = Result(self.query_str)
            return self.__result

    @property
    def report(self):
        if self.__report is not None:
            return self.__report
        else:
            prefix = self.result.execution_start.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S_")
            report_path = path.join(self.dir, prefix + self.basename)

            copyfile(self.source, report_path)

            with open(report_path, 'a') as executed_file:
                executed_file.write(REPORT_TEMPLATE.format(
                        start=self.result.execution_start.isoformat(),
                        end=self.result.execution_end.isoformat(),
                        duration=self.result.duration,
                        count=len(self.result.rows),
                        file=path.basename(self.export)
                ))

            self.__report = report_path
            return report_path

    @property
    def export(self):
        if self.__export is not None:
            return self.__export
        elif len(self.result.rows) == 0:
            return None
        else:
            prefix = self.result.execution_start.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S_")
            export_path = path.join(self.dir, prefix + self.raw_name + '.csv')

            with open(export_path, 'w') as export_file:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(export_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                csv_writer.writerow(self.result.description)
                for row in self.result.rows:
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)

            self.__export = export_path
            return export_path


def normalize_space(line):
    return re.sub(' +', ' ', line)


def strip_inline_comment(line):
    return re.sub('(--|#).*', '', line)


def is_blank(line):
    return not line.strip()


def is_comment(line):
    return line.strip().startswith('--') or line.strip().startswith('#')


class Result:

    def __init__(self, query_str):
        cursor = CursorProvider.cursor()
        self.execution_start = datetime.now()
        cursor.execute(query_str)
        self.execution_end = datetime.now()
        self.duration = self.execution_end - self.execution_start
        self.rows = cursor.fetchall()
        self.description = tuple(column[0] for column in cursor.description)
```

Here is the code with the same context being constructed three times.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import mock
import os.path

import query


def test_query_str():
    tested_query = query.Query('tests/assets/sample-query.sql')

    assert tested_query.query_str == "SELECT name, title FROM person LEFT JOIN job " \
                                     "ON person.job_id = job.id WHERE title NOT IN ('developer');"


def test_template_query_str():
    tested_query = query.Query('tests/assets/sample-template-query.sql',
                               template_vars=dict(job='developer', disappear='', donotexist=''))

    assert tested_query.query_str == "SELECT '{', '$jobs}', name, title FROM person LEFT JOIN job " \
                                     "ON person.job_id = job.id WHERE title IN ('developer') ;"


@mock.patch('query.CursorProvider')
@mock.patch('query.datetime')
def test_result(mock_datetime, mock_cp):
    mock_datetime.now.side_effect = (datetime(1992, 3, 4, 11, 0, 5, 654321),
                                     datetime(1992, 3, 4, 11, 0, 5, 987654))

    mock_cursor = mock.Mock()
    mock_cp.cursor.return_value = mock_cursor
    mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = [
        ('Adrien Horgnies', 'analyst developer'),
        ('Constance de Lannoy', 'secretary')
    ]
    mock_cursor.description = (('name',), ('title',))

    actual = query.Query('tests/assets/sample-query.sql').result

    assert actual.execution_start == datetime(1992, 3, 4, 11, 0, 5, 654321)
    assert actual.execution_end == datetime(1992, 3, 4, 11, 0, 5, 987654)
    assert actual.duration == timedelta(microseconds=333333)
    assert actual.rows == mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value
    assert actual.description == ('name', 'title')


@mock.patch('query.CursorProvider')
@mock.patch('query.datetime')
def test_report(mock_datetime, mock_cp, query_path, executed_query_path):
    mock_datetime.now.side_effect = (datetime(1992, 3, 4, 11, 0, 5, 654321),
                                     datetime(1992, 3, 4, 11, 0, 5, 987654))

    mock_cursor = mock.Mock()
    mock_cp.cursor.return_value = mock_cursor
    mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = [
        ('Adrien Horgnies', 'analyst developer'),
        ('Constance de Lannoy', 'secretary')
    ]
    mock_cursor.description = (('name',), ('title',))

    tested_query = query.Query(query_path)

    assert os.path.basename(tested_query.report) == '1992-03-04T11-00-05_query.sql'
    assert os.path.isfile(tested_query.report)
    assert [line for line in open(tested_query.report)] == [line for line in open(executed_query_path)]


@mock.patch('query.CursorProvider')
@mock.patch('query.datetime')
def test_export(mock_datetime, mock_cp, query_path, executed_export_path):
    mock_datetime.now.side_effect = (datetime(1992, 3, 4, 11, 0, 5, 654321),
                                     datetime(1992, 3, 4, 11, 0, 5, 987654))

    mock_cursor = mock.Mock()
    mock_cp.cursor.return_value = mock_cursor
    mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = [
        ('Adrien Horgnies', 'analyst developer'),
        ('Constance de Lannoy', 'secretary')
    ]
    mock_cursor.description = (('name',), ('title',))

    tested_query = query.Query(query_path)

    assert os.path.basename(tested_query.export) == '1992-03-04T11-00-05_query.csv'
    assert os.path.isfile(tested_query.export)
    assert [line for line in open(tested_query.export)] == [line for line in open(executed_export_path)]
```

In case you need context, [here is the repository](https://github.com/AdrienHorgnies/py-mysql-tracer/tree/6a911e5c3815669d20d474ed306f3841a9d82bcc)

**My question is, would you test it differently or would you code it differently ? How ?** Does these tests seem sensible to you ?

Comment: I don't quite understand how codereview works. I receive upvotes but not comments or answers. What does it mean ?